# Featured Image Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am having an issue with setting a featured image on a post as a custom role, when trying to set it my console says the response from the media library is "-1" and does not set the image (I also have an issue where I cannot upload assets as this custom role) whereas if I'm logged in as admin and do the exact same thing, it says:

```
{"success":true,"data":"<p class=\"hide-if-no-js\"><a title=\"Set featured image\" href=\"http:\/\/url-here.com\/de\/wp-admin\/media-upload.php?post_id=16262&#038;type=image&#038;TB_iframe=1\" id=\"set-post-thumbnail\" class=\"thickbox\"><img width=\"266\" height=\"198\" src=\"http:\/\/url-here.com\/wp-content\/usermedia\/ecm2-300x224.png\" class=\"attachment-266x266\" alt=\"ecm2\" \/><\/a><\/p><p class=\"hide-if-no-js\"><a href=\"#\" id=\"remove-post-thumbnail\" onclick=\"WPRemoveThumbnail('daf6fed443');return false;\">Remove featured image<\/a><\/p>"}
```

I've doubled check the capabilities and should be able to do it but have no clue.

Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code where you defined the custom role?

Comment: I am using the User Role Editor (pro version) so the plugin creates the role for me - https://www.role-editor.com.

Comment: If it's a pro version it should have support. Contact them.